# How to make the curls in an icecream?

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves, sculpting

Normally, in tutorials, we can make ice cream in this shape:

[image]

However, I want to make curls of this shape:

[image]

The curls of the ice cream in the second image are much more detailed and complex than in the first one, which we can easily make using a curve profile.

So long story short, my question is that how do we achieve the curls made by hand in the ice cream in the second image?

**Edit:**

The linked question could not solve my problem since the fluid simulation refuses to work in manta flow. Also, the bezier curves system is not working properly compared to the image, as shown in the first screenshot.

Is this possible? Are there any workarounds to this?

Comment: Use Path Curve in the Blender(Use Profile) and then use Ctrl+T in edit mode on verts to actually make curls.

Comment: @Wiseman Already tried it, but I don't get the required shape. I will try using the fluid simulation method in the linked question.

Answer (score 0):

You can make basic shape the way you do with the curve and profile and then just keep working on it. I would convert it to mesh, do some sculpting or maybe move some vertices with proportional editing, then it would be nice to have the ice-cream merge into itself so Voxel remesh sounds like a good tool for it, then some more sculpting.

Comment: Hmmm, nice idea. I'll try it, and if it works, I'll accept your answer.

Comment: No, curves do not work. The shape is extremely hard to achieve with it. If it's possible, could you demonstrate?

Comment: You have an image in your post that I assumed was made this way so that's probably the way to do it. It would not be so easy to achieve for me too :D, but I think it should be done this way. If I had to do I would just keep working with it until it starts looking decent. It seems like a fun challenge, its just that I am struggling with my own "extremely hard to achieve" tasks in Blender at work at the moment :D so I can't promise I will find time to give this a go. :D I imagine one might need a few attempts with this. My suggestion would be not to give up.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. But since I needed to do this immediately, I think I found a lazy workaround. I hope it works